# get timestamp of file and copy if recently modified

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im reading a file and checking the timestamps of the entries in that file... I want to check timestamps and if the time stamp has been modified from files with {/home/admin/backup}

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import argparse
import os


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-c', default="config.dat", help='file to read the config from')
args = parser.parse_args()

#this reads and prints times okay

f = open('config.dat','r')
list_contents = f.read().split('\n')
for a in list_contents:
    b = os.path.getmtime(a)


#problem is here. 



cache = dict((a, os.path.getmtime(a)) for a in list_contents)
print('cache')

#if file recently modified then do this next code:....
```

Comment: How would you define *"time stamp has been modified"*?

Comment: This script will form part of a cron job that will run at a set time and if it sees a modification in timestamp.... copy file again